# iOS Data Storage Guidelines after add NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey property

Tags: ios, storage, itunes-store, icloud-drive

I received, the next App review feedback:

> "We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 2.07 MB."

My app has the next data:

- An sqlite (352Kb) that when the app launch on first time it copies to device.
- Download and save on cache some images.

So, I read the documentation, and I add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey to all the files, and move to tmp directory (but I don't delete data after user exits, because I want to keep and not backup). I sent the app to Apple, and after review, I received the same feedback.

> "app stores 2.07 MB"

And In my device, after download all the images, when I go to:

- Install and launch your app
- Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
- If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
- Check your app's storage

It's just 376 KB and later 753KB.

I don't know what can I do next, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My app has been rejected for the same reason as yours but with the difference that my app doesn't downloads any document.

Maybe I'm not the better person to help you but your case looks like if your app downloads and saves the images two times (376 x 2 = 752) but I don't know how is created the other stored data (as happens in my app).

In my case, my app shows annotations in a map and opens URLs in a in-app web browser and I have no idea what documents are stored in iClouds (taking into account that I'm not using iCloud).